# Android XML Object Serialization

Tags: android, xml, serialization

I would like to serialize an object to XML inside Android.

Any libs suggested?

PS: Already tried XStream, but it doesn't serialize enums correctly with Android. The issue is here: [Serialization problem with Enums at Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533894/serialization-problem-with-enums-at-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a good solution for xml serialization of objects in Android yet.  Most of the existing solutions are too heavyweight for use in mobile apps, and depend on things Android doesn't support.

For an overview of XML options, see [working with xml in Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html).

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried simple http://simple.sourceforge.net/ it is working well for me, correctly handles enums, the jar is quite large though 320k.

Comment: this may be useful http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-xml-binding-simple-tutorial.html

Comment: sure but it has no depndencies!

Answer (score 1):

It's not XML, but you might want to use Google's GSON library to serialize objects. It's what they recommend in the their documentation as an alternative to [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html):

> JSON is concise, human-readable and efficient. Android includes both a streaming API and a tree API to read and write JSON. Use a binding library like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to read and write Java objects directly.