# sending the inputs to an URL in android

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

hi i am a new developer, in my app i have placed three edit text boxes, when the user fills up the edit box i want the data's inserted to be viewed as an XML file.

ie the following are edit text box columns
FirstName:***_***
lastName:***_*_**
DOB:***_*___**

when the user fills the spaces as Firstname:Siva
Lastname:Sankar
DOB:0206

actually i want these data's to be sent to a particular URL.

before that for checking purpose i want the data's to be printed as follows

`<usersdata>
       <firstname>Siva</firstname>
       <lastname>Sankar</lastname>
       <dob>0206</dob>
</usersdata>`

can anyone help me in doing this.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called XML Object Serialization. If you were looking to encode generic objects that's the way you should follow. Found a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587504/android-xml-object-serialization) that talks about serialization on the Android paltform (unfortunately you cannot use [XMLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) on the Android SDK).
Given that you only have this object to serialize (I suppose?), you can avoid the pain and create your little own serializer which generates your XML structure.

```
class UserObjectSerializer {

  Map<String, String> tagValue = new Map<String, String>();

  public UserObjectSerializer(User user) {
      tagValue["firstname"] = user.getFirstname();
      tagValue["lastname"] = user.getLastname();
      tagValue["dob"] = user.getDob();
  }

  public printXml() {
    // browse your Map and prints your <keys>values</keys>
    Set key = tagValue.keySet();
    Iterator it = key.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
       String tag = it.next();
       String value = tagValue.get(key);
       System.out.println("<" + tag + ">" + value + "</" + tag + ">");
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.