# Problem with "import java.beans.XMLEncoder" in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml-serialization, xmlencoder

I am trying to use XMLEncoder to serialize my java object for Android app which I need to further deserialize in c# server.

To import XMLEncoder in eclipse I use:

```
import java.beans.XMLEncoder;
```

The error i get for this import line is:

```
The import java.beans.XMLEncoder cannot be resolved
```

Pls give suggestions.

Comment: Please look at the [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587504/android-xml-object-serialization) link for other options as @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen already mentioned for the above method.

Comment: @Asad: Just wanted to know if this would be XML serializable compatible in c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [android.util.Xml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Xml.html).

Answer (score 1):

XMLencoder is not supported in Android, so you cannot use this approach.